# Ruby Array into string with brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, string

I have an array like so: ["data","data2"]

What would be the most Ruby-like way to convert this into a string with 
brackets included: "['data','data2']"

Thanks

Comment: `["data","data2"].to_s` ? whats wrong with this?

Comment: @rubish It will escape the double quotes. I think the op want to use single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say how "ruby-ish" this is, but it's what I would typically do:

```
puts "['" + array_of_strings.join("','") + "']"
```

Comment: `"['#{array_of_strings.join("','")}']"` looks better to me